# How can I show the date in the gnome 3 menubar?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

Gnome 3 has a menu bar that includes the day of the week and the time. The date and time settings allow the time to be shown in 24 hour or AM/PM style.

There do not appear, however, to be any options for displaying the date. Instead of "Thu 1:59 PM", I'd like it to read (for example) "1:59 PM, Thursday, March 28, 2013".

How can I configure the format of the date in the menu bar?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use dconf-editor to change many of the settings (GSettings) on your GNOME desktop environment. For this case you need to install the dconf-tools package. Run dconf-editor and find the appropriate key for your time settings.

e.g. `org.gnome.desktop.interface.clock-show-date`

Comment: Too bad the nice people of Gnome didn't put this setting in the UI. It's the date I need to glance to once in a while, I usually know what day it is.

Comment: Previously this was provided by the `org.gnome.shell.clock.show-date` key but has changed around GNOME 3.6. This may be changed graphically using the `gnome-teak-tool` UI, too.

Comment: @liberforce you have a typo: it is `gnome-tweak-tool` and thanks

Answer (score 20):

[To expand on what liberforce said]

1. launch ***`gnome-tweak-tool`***, sometimes called *Advanced Settings*
2. click the ***Shell*** menu, then enable ***Show date in clock***

Comment: I think it might be called `gnome-tweak` now.

Answer (score 0):

The gnome-tweak-tool works (the dconf-editor does not) debian 7(wheezy) ... however now the box is too narrow to display the time ... sigh

Turns out this is a "real-estate" issue , I used https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/112/remove-accesibility/  to recover a small bit of space, now I can see date AND time

Answer (score 0):

Activities -> Show Applications -> Tweaks

This program was preinstalled on my Debian installation.

Select `Top Bar` in the left menu.
Then enable `date`.

Answer (score -1):

In GNOME 3.28.2, this setting made the date show up in the top bar:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/interface/clock-show-date
```

Answer (score -1):

I use [GNOME Flashback](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback). The path to the relevant settings in `dconf-editor` is `/com/canonical/indicator/datetime/`:
[image]